# Selenium: Select indirect sibling element

Tags: java, selenium, select, selenium-webdriver, siblings

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="UFICommentContentBlock">
    <div class="UFICommentContent">
    <span>
    <span>
        <span data-ft="{"tn":"K"}">
            <span class="UFICommentBody">
                <span>My comment text</span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <div class="UFITranslatedText"></div>
    <span></span>
</div>
<div class="fsm fwn fcg UFICommentActions">
    <a class="UFILikeLink" data-ft="{"tn":">"}" data-testid="ufi_comment_like_link" href="#" role="button" title="Like this comment">Like</a>
    <span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"> · </span>
    <a class="UFIReplyLink" href="#" role="button">Reply</a>
    <span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"> · </span>
    <span>
</div>
<a class="UFICommentCloseButton _5upq _5upr _5upp _42ft" data-testid="ufi_comment_close_button" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-alignh="center" data-tooltip-content="Edit or delete this" href="#" id="js_c">   </a>
</div>
```

This is Facebook comment area.
I have several comments below the post, each is of the same structure.
I can find the required comment by

```
xpath("//div[@class='UFICommentContentBlock']//span[@class='UFICommentBody']//span[text()='My comment text']")
```

I need to reach the Edit comment button of this comment who is also child of `UFICommentContentBlock` but not a direct sibling of the element containing the comment text so

```
xpath("//div[@class='UFICommentContentBlock']//span[@class='UFICommentBody']//span[text()='.']/following-sibling::div[@class='fsm fwn fcg UFICommentActions']/a[@class='UFICommentCloseButton _5upq _5upr _5upp _42ft']")
```

doesn't work.
Need your assistance to select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:-

```
//span[text()='My comment text']/ancestor::div[@class='UFICommentContentBlock']//a[contains(@class,'UFICommentCloseButton')]
```

OR

```
//span[text()=.]/ancestor::div[@class='UFICommentContentBlock']//a[contains(@class,'UFICommentCloseButton')]
```

`ID` is also mentioned for `a` tag. So you can use id as well:-

```
//span[text()=.]/ancestor::div[@class='UFICommentContentBlock']//a[@id='js_c']
```

OR

```
//a[@id='js_c']
```